# Getting CORS error from api gatweway only when appending Auth0 token to request

Tags: angular, typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront

So I am trying to host a full stack web application in AWS. I have a angular frontend sitting in an s3 bucket behind cloudfront and using a domain from route53. On the backend I have an typescript express project that is sitting behind api gateway. I am using auth0 for authentication and the sample frontend/backend apps they provide on their websites. I will link them here:
https://github.com/auth0-developer-hub/spa_angular_typescript_hello-world
https://github.com/auth0-developer-hub/api_express_typescript_hello-world

When I make requests not hit by the interceptor they will work, but when I try requests that get modified by the interceptor (when I log in using auth0) I will get the below error:
"Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api-gateway.com/dev/api/messages/protected' from origin 'https://website.link' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

Interceptor code in the auth.module below:

```
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AuthModule, AuthHttpInterceptor } from '@auth0/auth0-angular';
import { environment as env } from '../environments/environment';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { SharedModule } from './shared';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    SharedModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AuthModule.forRoot({
      ...env.auth0,
      httpInterceptor: {
        allowedList: [`${env.api.serverUrl}/api/messages/admin`, `${env.api.serverUrl}/api/messages/protected`],
        //allowedList: [`${env.api.serverUrl}/api/messages/admin`],
      },
    }),
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: AuthHttpInterceptor,
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Below is my index.ts from the express backend where I explicitly allow the "Authorization" header that the interceptor is attaching. I have confirmed the tokens it is passing are valid as well.

```
import cors from "cors";
import * as dotenv from "dotenv";
import * as awsServerlessExpress from 'aws-serverless-express';
import express from "express";
import helmet from "helmet";
import nocache from "nocache";
import { messagesRouter } from "./messages/messages.router";
import { errorHandler } from "./middleware/error.middleware";
import { notFoundHandler } from "./middleware/not-found.middleware";

dotenv.config();

if (!(process.env.PORT && process.env.CLIENT_ORIGIN_URL)) {
  throw new Error(
    "Missing required environment variables. Check docs for more info."
  );
}

const PORT = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10);
const CLIENT_ORIGIN_URL = process.env.CLIENT_ORIGIN_URL;

const app = express();
const apiRouter = express.Router();

app.use(express.json());
app.set("json spaces", 2);

app.use(
  helmet({
    hsts: {
      maxAge: 31536000,
    },
    contentSecurityPolicy: {
      useDefaults: false,
      directives: {
        "default-src": ["'none'"],
        "frame-ancestors": ["'none'"],
      },
    },
    frameguard: {
      action: "deny",
    },
  })
);

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.contentType("application/json; charset=utf-8");
  next();
});
app.use(nocache());

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: CLIENT_ORIGIN_URL,
    methods: ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"],
    allowedHeaders: ["Authorization", "Content-Type"],
    maxAge: 86400,
  })
);

app.use("/api", apiRouter);
apiRouter.use("/messages", messagesRouter);

app.use(errorHandler);
app.use(notFoundHandler);

// create serverless express
const server = awsServerlessExpress.createServer(app);

// export the handler function for AWS Lambda
export const handler = (event: any, context: any) => awsServerlessExpress.proxy(server, event, context);
```

I have tried various things like setting the 'Access-Control-AllowOrigin' header on the routes and it still hasn't worked, such as below:

```
messagesRouter.get("/protected", validateAccessToken, (req, res) => {
  res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", CLIENT_ORIGIN_URL);
  try {
    logger.info(JSON.stringify(req.auth));
    logger.info(`Token: ${JSON.stringify(req.auth?.token)}`)
    //console.log(req.auth?.token)
    const message = getProtectedMessage();
  
    res.status(200).json(message);
  }
  catch (err){
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).json('Error')
  }
});
```

I've also tried various CORS configurations in the index.ts such as below:

```
app.use(cors());
```

```
app.use(cors({
  origin: CLIENT_ORIGIN_URL,
  methods: ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"],
  allowedHeaders: ["Authorization", "Content-Type"],
  credentials: true,
}));
```

These resulted in the same error

Edit: including my cloudfront configuration from terraform below:

```
resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "website_distribution" {
  origin {
    domain_name = aws_s3_bucket.frontend_bucket.bucket_regional_domain_name
    origin_id   = aws_s3_bucket.frontend_bucket.id

    s3_origin_config {
      origin_access_identity = aws_cloudfront_origin_access_identity.oai.cloudfront_access_identity_path
    }
  }

  origin {
    domain_name = replace(aws_api_gateway_deployment.example.invoke_url, "/^https?://([^/]*).*/", "$1")
    origin_id   = aws_api_gateway_deployment.example.id
    origin_path = "/${terraform.workspace}"

    custom_origin_config {
      http_port              = 80
      https_port             = 443
      origin_protocol_policy = "https-only"
      origin_ssl_protocols   = ["TLSv1", "TLSv1.1", "TLSv1.2"]
    }
  }

  default_cache_behavior {
    allowed_methods  = ["GET", "HEAD", "OPTIONS", "POST", "DELETE", "PUT", "PATCH"]
    cached_methods   = ["GET", "HEAD", "OPTIONS"]
    target_origin_id = aws_s3_bucket.frontend_bucket.id
    forwarded_values {
      query_string = false
      cookies {
        forward = "none"
      }
    }

    viewer_protocol_policy = "redirect-to-https"
    min_ttl                = 0
    default_ttl            = 3600
    max_ttl                = 86400
  }

  ordered_cache_behavior {
    path_pattern     = "/api/*"
    target_origin_id = aws_api_gateway_deployment.example.id

    allowed_methods = ["GET", "HEAD", "OPTIONS", "POST", "DELETE", "PUT", "PATCH"]
    cached_methods  = ["GET", "HEAD", "OPTIONS"]

    forwarded_values {
      query_string = true

      cookies {
        forward = "none"
      }

      headers = ["Authorization"]
    }

    viewer_protocol_policy = "redirect-to-https"
    min_ttl                = 0
    default_ttl            = 3600
    max_ttl                = 86400
  }

  restrictions {
    geo_restriction {
      restriction_type = "none"
      locations        = []
    }
  }

  viewer_certificate {
    acm_certificate_arn            = aws_acm_certificate.cert.arn
    ssl_support_method             = "sni-only"
    minimum_protocol_version       = "TLSv1.2_2018"
    cloudfront_default_certificate = false
  }

  custom_error_response {
    error_code            = 403
    response_page_path    = "/index.html"
    response_code         = "200"
    error_caching_min_ttl = 300
  }

  enabled             = true
  is_ipv6_enabled     = true
  http_version        = "http2"
  price_class         = "PriceClass_100"
  default_root_object = "index.html"
  aliases             = [var.domain_name[terraform.workspace], "www.${var.domain_name[terraform.workspace]}"]
}
```

Comment: Does this work locally but not in AWS? Have you tried `allowedList: ['/api/messages/admin', '/api/messages/protected'],`? Without website host. If the endpoint url is actually something like `/api/messages/proctected?<something>` or `/api/messages/proctected/<something>`, then you should use wildcard. `/api/messages/*` would allow both messages/protected and messages/admin, but might not be ideal

Comment: Yeah, it works when I spin up the frontend/backend locally. Also works when I grab the token from dev tools and call it from postman. Just not with the domain.

Comment: Sorry, meant to ask if it works with local frontend + backend on AWS. There are many configurations, mainly in cloudfront, that could solve your issue. Have you set up cloudfront origins, which works like Angular's `proxy.conf.json`?

Comment: All good. I just appended my cloudfront terraform configuration to my post if that helps. It does work when I just call it from api gateway. I'm guessing you're asking what happens if I just use the s3 bucket address directly? When I tried that it actually started complaining about wanting to come from a secure host or something. I can try it again but will have to change some roles and origin access identity settings.

Comment: Thanks for updating with Terraform configuration. In order to access API Gateway from Cloudfront, which happens when you issue `https://cloudfront-host/api/endpoint`, you need to define another origin, which is the api gateway. Inside of the new the origin definition you shall use [`custom_origin_config`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cloudfront_distribution#custom-origin-config-arguments) instead of `s3_origin_config`. Also read about `ordered_cache_behavior`, you might need to tweak it. That's why you can get to it through postman directly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this issue by enabling CORS for my resource in API Gateway. I also made sure to specify that the "Authorization" header is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

In order to access API Gateway from Cloudfront, which happens when you issue `https://cloudfront-host/api/endpoint`, you need to define another origin other than S3, which is the api gateway.

The reason you can access directly through Postman or Api Gateway is because Cloudfront is the one who is blocking the request. You'll also need to setup `ordered_cache_behavior`, so that Cloudfront can proxy requests to your custom origin. This is very similar to `proxy.conf.json` in Angular, where if all your api endpoints are following the pattern `/api/<endpoint>`, then your ordered cache behavior will route requests to `/api/*` to api gateway.

Inside of the new the origin definition you shall use [`custom_origin_config`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cloudfront_distribution#custom-origin-config-arguments) instead of `s3_origin_config`. Also read about `ordered_cache_behavior`, you might need to tweak it.

```
resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "website_distribution" {
  origin {
    domain_name = aws_s3_bucket.frontend_bucket.bucket_regional_domain_name
    origin_id   = aws_s3_bucket.frontend_bucket.id

    s3_origin_config {
      origin_access_identity = aws_cloudfront_origin_access_identity.oai.cloudfront_access_identity_path
    }
  }

  origin {
    domain_name = <>
    origin_id   = <some_id>

    custom_origin_config {
      ...
    }
  }

  ordered_cache_behavior {
    path_pattern     = "/api/*"
    ...
    target_origin_id = <some_id>
    ...
  }

...
```

Comment: Hate to say it but I've still been dealing with the same error :/. I included my new terraform configuration which includes the api gateway origin configuration. Not sure if anything looks off there or not.